# How to remove white space between nested divs

Tags: html, css, whitespace, divider

How can you remove white space between divs nested within each other. For example

```
  <div>
   <div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: In what language? Do you mean the visual whitespace once the divs have rendered in the browsers, or do you mean the whitespace / new lines in your html source file?

Comment: I mean after rendering. Usually it is done like starting a comment at the end of a div and then finish comment at the start of a new div.

Comment: Set {margin: -1px;} for the inner div. My situation was: I had a nested div and I wanted the border to be seamless with a nested div. Since I was using view port units at certain sizes, it would set the border to a size which would show a 1 pixel gap between the border of the parent and nested div. Setting margin to -1px seemd to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you specify which space are you referring to with reference to the below link
http://jsfiddle.net/meghanagpal/4khuL01a/1/

```
HTML
<div class="default"></div>
<div class="default"></div>
CSS
.default{    
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: You don't have nested divs in your fiddle. I want one div inside another. And then in browser empty space is rendered outside of divs

Comment: Try this updated fiddle and highlight your issue with reference to that http://jsfiddle.net/meghanagpal/4khuL01a/2/

Comment: Where is updated fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/meghanagpal/4khuL01a/2/

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS to your code

```
div{
  margin: 0;
}
```

or add inline CSS to your div like this

```
<div style="margin:0"></div>
```